# Build a project in local jenkins CI and deploy that project to remote server like Digital Ocean

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, digital-ocean

I am totally new in jenkins. Recently i learned very basic jenkins CI process in my local pc. All works fine. Now i wanna deploy a project from my local jenkins CI to digital ocean server. Mentioning that i use GIT and Jenkins locally and don't wanna use remote server for GIT like github, bitbucket etc. I googled but i found all the tutorial is based on remote server and everybody uses jenkins and GIT remotely. Would you please suggest me tutorial what can i do or how can i reach to my goal? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: From your local Jenkins take backup of your job using Thin Backup Plugin.
Then , create the instance on digital ocean server , ssh with Github , Then create a Jenkins user on it and on their Jenkins UI , put your jobs which you have taken from local. Digital Ocean server gives you dedicated server so you have to ssh with Github to use on it.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your suggestion for me. Is there any tutorial about it? thanks.